# Creating a new QuoteLineItem results in error

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, method

I have a button on one of my visualforce pages thats meant to allow a user to click on the button and add a new QuoteLineItem to the list of QuoteLineItems. My first major error is that the `Standard_Price_Not_Defined,` and I also am not so sure if the code will even work. Any help?

Here is the code for the **button**:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add Item" action="{!addNewProduct}" reRender="thePageBlock" />
```

And heres the code for the **apex method** it calls:

```
public void addNewProduct(){
    Product2 addProd = new Product2(name='New Product');
    insert addProd;
    Pricebook2 pbook = new Pricebook2(name='newPbook');
    insert pbook;
    PriceBookEntry newPBE = new PriceBookEntry(Product2Id=addProd.id, UseStandardPrice = true, Pricebook2Id=pbook.id, UnitPrice=1);
    insert newPBE;
    QuoteLineItem qteLI = new QuoteLineItem(QuoteId=myQuote.id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=0, PricebookEntryId=newPBE.id, Product2Id=addProd.id);
    qli.add(qteLI);
    insert qteLI;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are creating a new Product, Pricebook, and PricebookEntry every time. The error basically means that since the product was just created, there is no PricebookEntry for it in the Standard Pricebook.
What you want to do is find the pricebook being used on the Quote and the associated PricebookEntry corresponding to the product, and create your QuoteLineItem from that.

Comment: Thank you! also how would i get the page to automatically refresh? the rerender doesn't seem to update fields that get affected by fields that are being edited, ex: Change unit price but Total Price doesn't change. (Theyre input fields)

Comment: To make rerender work, you should use an Apex property that holds the values you want to display. The property should be used in the Visualforce page.
In your case, if you want to display the new Quote Line Item added, just store your quote line items in a list and make it property. In your action addNewProduct, add the new record to that list.

Comment: To add onto that, make sure that your action/button rerenders the appropriate areas of the page